# Why CSS loader of webpack not working?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, css-loader

I am making the toy example described in the documentation of css-loader:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader

I also tried this basic guide that suggest the same: https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-2-getting-started/

However, both VS Code highlight and when bundling through the command line complain that the module of the CSS file is not available. Like it does not really recognize it. I have checked I indeed really have installed css-loader, webpack etc. Other than the css loader, webpack is working fine for javascript, typescript etc. So it is really just a problem with CSS. Any ideas why failing?

The error I get is:

> ```
>   TS2307: Cannot find module 'styles.css'.
> ```

My file:

```
import test from 'styles.css';
```

I tried also without file extension, with and without curly braces etc. But really followed the toy example in the docu of css-loader.

My webpack.config file:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

const config = {
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.js', '.css']
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'title Cool!',
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.tsx$/, 
        loader: "ts-loader" ,
      },
      {
        test: /.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ],
      }
    ]
  }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: share your webpack config file .and also the structure of your code, cause we need to know the structure to help u navigate to style file.

Comment: I followed the example in the official docu:https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader

Comment: I also tried this guide that does almost the same with the same error as described in the post: https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-2-getting-started/

Comment: I think its better you share the code.

Comment: Most likely the path to styles.css is wrong. If styles.css is in the same folder as the file you've tried to import from, try `import test from './styles.css';`

Comment: check whether CSS file path is correct not ? right click on import statement in VSC and click on 'Go to Definition'. If it wont open the file then the path is not correct

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need a named import? This should work: `import './styles.css';`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to typescript and not to webpack or the css loader.
So I needed to add css files to modules for typescript:

```
declare module '*.css' {
    const content: any;
    export default content;
}
```

Did the trick. No clue why this is not mention in any of the dozens of tutorial and guides I saw.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a **relative path** to your file:

```
import test from './path/to/styles.css';
```

Comment: TS2307: Cannot find module 'styles.css'.

Comment: is this this the only place you tried to import `'styles.css'`? i would expect to see cannot find module `'./styles.css'`